# SQL conundrum - date filter doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, where-clause

Really scratching my head here.  I have a query that has a date filter.  However, I keep getting results that lie outside my date filter period!  I have checked that my column is indeed a date column, I have tried using Between and >= <= and none of these seem to have the slightest impact.

Here is an example of my code.

```
Declare @PARAM_REPORTING_START_DATE as datetime
Declare @PARAM_REPORTING_END_DATE as datetime
Declare @PARAM_CRDTR_ID as integer


Set @PARAM_REPORTING_START_DATE = '2015/06/12'-- 05:39:44 AM'
Set @PARAM_REPORTING_END_DATE = '2015/06/24'-- 05:39:44 AM'
Set @PARAM_CRDTR_ID = 1005

  --select @PARAM_REPORTING_START_DATE, @PARAM_REPORTING_END_DATE

  Select distinct
  capj.cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_jrnl_id, 
  c.cnsmr_nm_prfx_txt,
  c.cnsmr_nm_frst_txt,
  c.cnsmr_nm_lst_txt,
  capj.cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt,
  isdate(capj.cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt) as is_date,
  capj.bckt_trnsctn_typ_cd as capj_bckt_trnsctn_typ_cd ,
  pm.pymnt_memo_nm
  from 
  cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_jrnl capj 
    inner join cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl cpj 
        on capj.cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl_id = cpj.cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl_id
    inner join pymnt_memo pm 
        on pm.pymnt_memo_id = cpj.pymnt_memo_id
    inner join crdtr cr 
        on capj.crdtr_id = cr.crdtr_id
    inner join cnsmr_accnt ca
        on ca.cnsmr_accnt_id = capj.cnsmr_accnt_id
    inner join cnsmr c on c.cnsmr_id = ca.cnsmr_id
Where 
    capj.cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt>=@PARAM_REPORTING_START_DATE
     and 
    capj.cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt<=@PARAM_REPORTING_END_DATE
     and
    ( -1 IN ( @PARAM_CRDTR_ID ) )   OR ( cr.crdtr_ID in (@PARAM_CRDTR_ID) )
```

Comment: OR ( cr.crdtr_ID in (@PARAM_CRDTR_ID) )
so if this true, the other where clause are not important anymore, you must add some extra brackets
 and
(    ( -1 IN ( @PARAM_CRDTR_ID ) )   OR ( cr.crdtr_ID in (@PARAM_CRDTR_ID) ))

Comment: `AND` takes precedence over `OR`. You effectively have `where (A and B and C) or D` instead of `where A and B and (C or D)`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers!  Much appreciate it!  So happy to have solved this problem (even if I feel like an idiot!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misplacement of braces

```
Where 
    capj.cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt>=@PARAM_REPORTING_START_DATE
     and 
    capj.cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt<=@PARAM_REPORTING_END_DATE
     and
    ( -1 IN ( @PARAM_CRDTR_ID )    OR  cr.crdtr_ID in (@PARAM_CRDTR_ID) )
```

Comment: like my answer but later.

Comment: I feel like an idiot!  Was so busy focusing on the date part of the filter I ignored the 2nd part!  Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will get all results that satisfy

```
OR ( cr.crdtr_ID in (@PARAM_CRDTR_ID) )
```

so the date filter doesn't matter.

You should rearrange the the brackets/braces in your `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
WHERE 
        capj.cnsmr_accnt_pymnt_pstd_dt
            BETWEEN @PARAM_REPORTING_START_DATE AND @PARAM_REPORTING_END_DATE
    AND
        (
            @PARAM_CRDTR_ID = -1
        OR
            @PARAM_CRDTR_ID = cr.crdtr_ID
        );
```